# CUDA shared memory occupancy

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

If I have a 48kB shared memory per SM and I write a kernel where I allocate 32kB shared memory that means that only 1 block can be running on one SM at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Shared memory must support the "footprint" of all "resident" threadblocks.  In order for a threadblock to be launched on a SM, there must be enough shared memory to support it.  If not, it will wait until the presently executing threadblock has finished.

There is some nuance to this arriving with [Maxwell GPUs](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/maxwell-most-advanced-cuda-gpu-ever-made/) (cc 5.0, 5.2).  These GPUs support either 64KB (cc 5.0) or 96KB (cc 5.2) of shared memory.  In this case, the maximum shared memory available to a single threadblock is still limited to 48KB, but multiple threadblocks may use more than 48KB in aggregate, on a single SM.  This means a cc 5.2 SM could support 2 threadblocks, even if both were using 32KB shared memory.